# How can I implement composite Views of composite ViewModels?

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm just getting into my first project with (the unbelieveably excellent) MVVMCross and I can't figure out how to do something that seems fairly basic: composite views.

Suppose I've got a `Person` (FirstName, LastName, etc), and a person has an `Address` (Street, City, PostalCode, etc.).  So I'll also have a `PersonViewModel` and an `AddressViewModel`.

This is a strictly tablet based app (iPad only, actually) and I want to use containment to have the `PersonView` contain the (reusable) `AddressView`, such that the outer (person) view binds to `Person`, while the inner (address) view binds to `Person.Address`.

I (dimly) understand the presenter concept for showing the views, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514772/composite-views-in-mvvmcross), but I can't see how to handle the propagation of changes from Person to Address and back.

Suppose the Person object has an Address object, but the `PersonViewModel` shows the `AddressViewModel` in  an AddressView by passing some sort of Address id and rehydrating.  Then the AddressView is binding to a **different** Address object than the one the Person contains.  I don't see how to keep the two in sync, which of course would defeat the whole purpose of binding.

How should I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Not 100% positive (hence me making this a comment and not an answer), but if you name your variables the same thing in each of them (Person vs. PersonViewModel, etc...), the binding should occur "automatically" when you pass the PersonViewModel or AddressViewModel through your view, and try to get it back in your controller or something of that nature as a Person or Address itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a really wide topic...

...and there are lots of possible answers.

I think it's important to consider ViewModel's as a very simple concept - I'd like to encourage you to think of ViewModels just as being models for views - definitely don't think of them as 'whole page' objects.

....

Within MvvmCross, you can use `ShowViewModel` and custom presenters to change the UI if you want to - and this is demonstrated in several MvvmCross examples including the split view presenter - http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/05/n24-splitviewpresenter-n1-days-of.html

This `ShowViewModel` technique is really useful for `navigation` - for changing the whole page or for significant portions of it.

However, you don't have to use navigation paradigms if your app doesn't need them.

If you want to, then you can instead:

- build your own hierarchies of viewmodels within the core
- and you can then build your own databound hierarchies of views within the UIs

It's entirely up to you - **your app is king**.

....

I feel like I'm not explaining this very well...

....

So I gave up and recorded this video - maybe it helps: http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n32-truth-about-viewmodels-starring.html

The video and sample code only covers the iPad, but I hope it's easy(ish) to see how you would extend it to other platforms:

- for Windows you can use `UserControl`
- for Android you can use `MvxFrameControl`, custom view or `Fragment` code.

Comment: Stuart, that has to hold some kind of record for most thorough stackoverflow answer ever.  The video answered my question, and the 14 or so follow up questions I was getting ready to have, and taught me so much about what I need to do.  I had been feeling a little ill about how to architect my data intensive app given the lack of any coherent binding mechanism in iOS, but having discovered MVVMCross, I am now very excited to begin.  Thank you *so* much!

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that allows Control navigation in addition to the default Views navigation, hope it helps: https://github.com/ChristianRuiz/MvvmCross-ControlsNavigation

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this implementation of a custom presenter for MvvmCross projects. To support Fragments in android and also multiple fragments into one other fragment/activity:

https://github.com/JelleDamen/CustomMvxAndroidPresenter